# Calculate the sum of matrices in a list or a 3D array

Tags: arrays, list, r

Given a list (length = n) of 2x2 matrices, how do I calculate the sum of all those matrices (and get a 2x2 matrix) ?

How can I do it, if instead of a list I have those matrices in a (2 x 2 x n) dimensional array ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition

Comment: @Xupypr MV It would be more than enough if there wasn't the `r` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sum of matrices in a list:

```
Reduce("+", matrix_list)
```

Comment: Very elegant. I tried `do.call` without success. I think that I must try to understand and use the `Reduce` function.

Comment: Anyone know why all the functional programming functions like `Map` and `Reduce` are capitalized?

Answer (score 4):

I would mess with arrays so if you got a `list` e.g.:

```
n <- 5
someList <- lapply(1:n, function(i) matrix(1:4+(i-1)*4,2,2))
```

transform it to 3d `array`

```
someArray <- array(unlist(someList ), c(2,2,n))
```

Now you could use `rowSums`

```
rowSums(someArray, dims=2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   45   55
# [2,]   50   60
```

Comment: I was close to find this. It's that `dims` parameter that I was missing.